# Unable to run Mockito junit test

Tags: junit, mockito

I am very new to JUnit. I wrote a simple JUnit test case which gives `NullPointerException`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Controller control;

    @Mock 
    Service service;

    @Test
    public void postTest() throws IOException {

        //Given

        Object o = new Object();

                //initialise the object here which the service layer would return

        String a = "abcd";
        Integer b = 5;
        Mockito.when(service.Post(a,o)).thenReturn(o);

        Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> object = control.Post(a,o);

        StepVerifier.create(object)
        .consumeNextWith(entity -> {
            assertEquals(b,entity.getBody().get());
        })
        .expectComplete();
```

I get a `NullPointerException` for this scenario.

Comment: Can you post the line where you are getting NPE?

Comment: o = service.post(a, o);

Comment: Your code has a `service.Post`, and you mentioned `service.post`. Can you double check your method names? Just to make sure... Everything seems to be find with your code... I need more details.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.....I have autowired the service class in my controller class and service class in turn has an autowiring done for the repository class which interacts with database. I have one autowiring for the NativeWebRequest also done in the controller class.

Comment: On your `Mockito.when` statement, try substituting the arguments "a" and "o" for `Mockito.anyString()` and `Mockito.anyInt()` respectively. See if it helps.

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace to the question?